# how can i know when i reach end of a datareader?

Tags: c#, database, sqldatareader

```
cmd.CommandText = "select name from Tbl_Shahr_No";
SqlDataReader reader = null;
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();

while(reader.HasRows)
{
    ddl.Items.add(reader["name"].tostring());
    reader.read()
}
```

i wrote this code but problem is that while statement is true all times!
how can i read all of reader information with a `while` or repeater ring?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest idea is to simply let `Read()` be the loop condition.

```
while (reader.Read())
{
     // grab data
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the [`.Read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read.aspx) method in your `while`.

> It advances the SqlDataReader to the next record.
>
> Returns true if there are more rows; otherwise false.

```
while(reader.Read())
{
   ddl.Items.add(reader["name"].ToString());
}
```

**Alternatively, data-bind your dropdownlist to your SqlDataReader**, and don't bother iterating it manually.

```
ddl.DataSource = reader;
ddl.DataTextField = "name";
ddl.DataValueField = "name";
ddl.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 3):

`IDataReader.Read()` returns a bool. Use it as the condition for your while-loop:

```
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();            
while(reader.Read())
{
    ddl.Items.add(reader["name"].tostring());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When reader.Read() returns false then there are no more rows so by using

```
while(reader.Read())
{
    //do some thing here
}
```

it will loop until there are no more rows!

But if the datareader has more then one dataset use the following

```
while(reader.Read())
{
    //First dataset
    //do some thing here
}
reader.NextResult();
while(reader.Read())
{
    //Second dataset
    //do some thing here
}
......
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while (reader.read())
{
   // do your thing here for each row read
}
```